# Use .csv file name in python for-loop

Tags: python, csv, pandas, matplotlib, namespaces

I have some code that takes a bunch of csv files and makes individual plots using the data. I was able to get help on the code (see here: [Automate making multiple plots in python using several .csv files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42430387/automate-making-multiple-plots-in-python-using-several-csv-files)) but now I want to alter it such that wherever the code says `name` will be replaced with the name of the file in the `files` vector. For some reasons this works in the final line of code `plt.savefig('{}.png'.format(fn))` but nowhere else.

```
import pandas as pd
from dateutil import parser, rrule
from datetime import datetime, time, date
import time
import os
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

files = ['a.pd.csv',
    't.pd.csv',
    'r.pd.csv',
    'n.pd.csv',
    'm.pd.csv',
    'k.pod.csv']

for f in files:
    fn = f.split('.')[0]
    dat = pd.read_csv(f)
    df0 = dat.loc[:, ['TimeStamp', 'RF']]
        # Change time format
    df0["time"] = pd.to_datetime(df0["TimeStamp"])
    df0["day"] = df0['time'].map(lambda x: x.day)
    df0["month"] = df0['time'].map(lambda x: x.month)
    df0["year"] = df0['time'].map(lambda x: x.year)
    df0.to_csv("name_1.csv", na_rep="0")  # write to csv

    # Combine for daily rainfall
    df1 = pd.read_csv('name_1.csv', encoding='latin-1',
                  usecols=['day', 'month', 'year', 'RF', 'TimeStamp'])
    df2 = df1.groupby(['day', 'month', 'year'], as_index=False).sum()
    df2.to_csv("name_2.csv", na_rep="0", header=None)  # write to csv

    # parse date
    df3 = pd.read_csv("name_2.csv", header=None, index_col='datetime',
                 parse_dates={'datetime': [1,2,3]},
                 date_parser=lambda x: pd.datetime.strptime(x, '%d %m %Y'))

    def dt_parse(date_string):
        dt = pd.datetime.strptime(date_string, '%d %m %Y')
        return dt

    # sort datetime
    df4 = df3.sort()
    final = df4.reset_index()

    # rename columns
    final.columns = ['date', 'bleh', 'rf']

    final[['date','rf']].plot()

    plt.suptitle('Name Rain 2015-2016', fontsize=20) #changename
    plt.xlabel('DOY', fontsize=18)
    plt.ylabel('Rain / mm', fontsize=16)

    plt.savefig('{}.png'.format(fn))
```

Comment: Which lines exactly?  Do you mean just the `suptitle()`?  If so something like `plt.suptitle('Name: {}'.format(fn), fontsize=20)` would work.

Comment: Yup! That works.. Thanks. One other question though.. Do you know how to make the first letter capital in the text that I substitute in the {brackets}?

Comment: Change `fn` to `fn.title ()`

Comment: Hm.That didn't work for me... Also can you check my other question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42444020/change-frequency-of-x-axis-tick-label-of-datetime-data-in-python-bar-chart-using

Comment: To change the graph title to start with a capital I meant you could use `plt.suptitle('Name: {}'.format(fn.title()), fontsize=20)`

Comment: That worked! Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed my own problem: `df2.to_csv('{}_2.csv'.format(fn), na_rep="0", header=None)  # write to csv`